# Cómo enviar 2 valores desde la vista hasta el controlador?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Necesito mandar 2 valores al controlador, uno de los valores es fijo y el otro es un valor dinámico que es traído desde un `ViewModel`.

El valor dinámico es mostrado en una tabla, y es un input, de tipo `submit`, el cual si hago clic sobre él, el valor tanto fijo como dinámico trato de enviarlos a un método del controlador, pero éstos parece no estar llegando. Quería saber si me podrían ayudar a mandarlos y que éstos lleguen.

Esta es mi vista:

```
     <tbody>
        <form action="~/Home/LeerOpcion" method="post">
              <label hidden value="entrega" name="seleccion"></label>
                   @foreach (var item in Model)
                   {
                                <tr>
                                    <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-link" value="@item.NumeroEntrega" name="identi">@item.NumeroEntrega</button></td>
                                    <td>@item.NumeroPedido</td>
                                    <td>@item.NumeroRemito</td>
                                    <td>@item.CantFotos</td>
                                    <td>@item.Fecha</td>
                                    <td>@item.Hora</td>
                                </tr>
                  }
        </form>
     </tbody>
```

Y ésto es mi metodo del controlador:

```
 public IActionResult LeerOpcion(string seleccion, string identi)
        {
            List<PedidoViewModel> listaPedidos;

            try
            {
                identi = CleanString(identi);

                if (identi == null || identi == "")
                {
                    return View("Index");
                }

                switch (seleccion)
                {
                    case "pedido":
                        listaPedidos = VerPedido(identi);
                        return View("Pedido", listaPedidos);
                    case "remito":
                        listaPedidos = VerRemito(identi);
                        return View("Pedido", listaPedidos);
                    case "entrega":
                        listaPedidos = VerEntrega(identi);
                        return View("Pedido", listaPedidos);
                }

                return View();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ViewBag.error = ex.Message;
                return View("Error");
            }
```

Desde la vista quiero mandar el valor del label (name="seleccion", value="entrega") y del input (name="identi", value="@item.NumeroEntrega").

Probé con el form, con el `@using(Html.Beginform)`... con un `onclick=@Url.Action("LeerOpcion", "Home", new{seleccion = "entrega", identi = @item.NumeroEntrega})`en el `input`/`button`

Alguien me puede ayudar porfa?

Comment: sip, esta marcado como Post, y el metodo funciona ya que tambien lo estoy utilizando para un `select`

Comment: Tienes un campo (NumeroEntrega) en un botón debe ir en in input, luego el otro campo dónde está???

Comment: probe con input y tampoco funcionó, el otro campo está justo debajo de abrir el form (`<label>`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que tienes muchos errores de conceptos. Para enviar algo debes ponerlo en un input.

Si quieres que esté oculto, puedes poner:

```
<input type="hidden" value="entrega" name="seleccion">
```

Además tienes un Form y dentro de él tienes un foreach. Cuando haces esto, el submit enviará todos los campos dentro del form, cuando entiendo que tú quieres enviar solo el seleccionado.
(si quieres enviar todo, el controlador debe recibir un array)

Luego tu controlado envía devuelta una vista, por lo que entiendo que el acto de presionar un botón cambias de página, entonces deberías poner algo asi:

```
<tbody>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td><a class="btn btn-primary" href="~/Home/LeerOpcion?seleccion=entrega&identi=@item.NumeroEntrega" >@item.NumeroEntrega</a></td>
        <td>@item.NumeroPedido</td>
        <td>@item.NumeroRemito</td>
        <td>@item.CantFotos</td>
        <td>@item.Fecha</td>
        <td>@item.Hora</td>
    </tr>
}
     
</tbody>
```

Y el controlador

```
[HttpGet("LeerOpcion")]
public IActionResult LeerOpcion(string seleccion, string identi)
{
 //tu código
}
```